Error in Azure Pipelines when trying to create database contained user in Azure Sql for Azure Function App
I have an Azure Sql server and a specific database where I want to create a contained user representing my Azure Function App.
I have already done the following:

Enabled the system-assigned managed identity (SMI) of both the Azure Sql Server and the Azure Function App resources.
Created an AAD user group and assign it the AAD role Directory Readers and added as a member the service principal of the managed identity of my Azure Sql Server resource.
Created an Azure release pipeline to test that I can run a SQL script to create a db contained user for my Azure Function App. The Azure Pipeline runs with a service connection which has been associated with another Entra ID service principal with access to my resource groups. Inside the Azure Pipeline, I used an Azure SQL Database deployment task setup as follows:




Option
Value




Azure Service Connection Type
Azure Resource Manager


Azure Subscription
I selected a service connection associated with an Entra ID service principal for deploying resources to my selected resource groups


SQL Database



Authentication Type
Service Principal


Azure SQL Server
******.database.windows.net


Database
******


Deployment Package



Deploy type
Inline SQL Script


Inline SQL Script
CREATE USER [my-func-dev-weu] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo; GO;ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [my-func-dev-weu];GO






Firewall



Specify Firewall Rules Using
AutoDetect


Delete Rule After Task Ends
Checked



When I execute my Azure Pipeline I get back the following error:
Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting

Unfortunately, the troubleshooting guide was not much of help for my issue.
I am a bit confused because although I created the system-assigned managed identity of my Azure Sql server, I have no way of using it (the service principal) to execute my Azure SQL database deployment task. I was under the impression that the service principal authentication will check that the Azure Sql server's SMI is enabled and it will carry on creating the new contained user.
Next, I tried to manually add the service principal associated with the service connection I use to deploy my resources to Azure and it worked (I had already added the service principal of the service connection to my AAD user group with Directory Readers role), but I don't like this solution, because it means I shall always have to execute the manual task to add the azure pipeline's service principal as a contained user to every Azure Sql database I need to be able to create contained users via Azure release Pipeline.
How can I make it work by only using the SMI of the Azure SQL Server when executing the db script within an Azure release Pipeline ?

Are you using the Service Principal type service connection in Azure SQL Deployment task? You can try to use the managed identity type ARM service connection and check the result. I tried to manually add the service principal associated with the service connection I use to deploy my resources to Azure and it worked  Can you share more details about how to let the service principal work?

Hi Kevin, just like I said, when I setup the service principal of my service connection to be a contained user in my database AND be a member of the user group assigned the Directory Readers role, it worked. Alas, I don't like this solution because I'll have to manually add the service principal of every service connection I use as a contained user in every database I target.
I shall create a UMI, add it as an identity to my Azure Sql Server, create a service connection based on it and use Service Principal auth in the deploy task w/ the SP, w/out adding the UMI as a contained user to my db

The azure sql server system managed identity can not be used in Service connection. You need to create the User managed identity to let the service connection work. And you are required to use a self-hosted agent on an Azure VM in order to use managed service identity.

Yes, I refer to a UMI (User-assigned Managed Identity), not a system-assigned managed identity.

When you create the ARM service connection based on UMI, it should work. You can refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-to-a-vm-that-uses-a-managed-identity But the piepline needs to use a self-hosted agent on Azure VM(which use the same UMI).

I cannot use the self-hosted agent on Azure VM due to costs. Is there an alternative solution to my issue?
I would be happy if I could add my service connection service principal to my Azure SQL server as an "admin account", so that I could create database contained users to any of the databases on the server via my Azure Pipeline. Is that a possible scenario? If it is, can you please share some documentation links on how to achieve this?

could add my service connection service principal to my Azure SQL server as an "admin account"  Yes. This can be achieved. You can set the Service Principal as admin in   **Microsoft Entra admin ** in Azure SQL Server. Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#azure-portal Then the Service Principal can have the access to do all actions.

And you can use the Azure PowerShell/ Azure CLI command to integrate this step in Pipeline.
